Flutter only reads FastAPI StreamingResponse at the end of the stream
Overview
I'm currently experimenting on a Stream functionality so I can later integrate it with a software i'm building. I'm trying to stream information from my backend built with FastAPI, to my frontend, built with Flutter.
I have a GET endpoint in my backend to which I request the stream data from my frontend application. The endpoint integration in itself is working well, so the issues are regarding the implementation of the stream functionality.
If there is any information that I have not provided here but may be needed to better understand the problem, please don't hesitate in asking me to provide it. This feature is really important to me, and I would love to get it working :)
I'll explain below the issue i'm encountering.
Problem
From what I researched in the Internet, using the FastAPI StreamResponse will let me send packets of information to a stream that'll be read by the frontend of my application, from a GET request to the endpoint.
The backend correctly sends the information in intervals through the StreamResponse, but my frontend seems to freeze until all the information has arrived, and I have closed the stream.
FastAPI Backend Endpoint
The backend code I wrote to send information via Stream.
async def fake_streamer():
    for _ in range(10):
        print("Sending frame")
        yield b"Hey!"
        time.sleep(1)
    
@app.get("/camera/{camera_id}")
def read_camera(camera_id: int):
    return StreamingResponse(fake_streamer())

Flutter Frontend Request
Code that makes the request to the backend endpoint. This function is called when I click on an ElevatedButton, for simplicity.
void fetchData() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8001/camera/30');
    final client = http.Client();

    try {
      final request = http.Request('GET', url);
      final response = await client.send(request);
      await for (var data in response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder)) {
        print(data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  }

Video demonstration
On the left is my backend console logs, and in the right my Flutter logs. Screen print was taken  while transmitting the information via Stream.

On the left is my backend console logs, and in the right my Flutter logs. Screen print was taken at the end of transmitting the information via Stream, and closing it.

Approaches tried
I tried two different approaches to this feature, and both had the same result (Flutter receiving all packets at the end of transmission, or websocket connection close):

Websocket approach
Stream approach

Resources read:

Video Streaming App using FastAPI and OpenCV
Streaming video from camera in FastAPI results in frozen image after first frame
Other stackoverflow (or reddit, don't remember) post regarding websocket data transmission. Lost the link

Update #1
Tried a workaround from a suggestion that I was awaiting for the whole stream to resolve. Behaviour remains unchanged.
...
      final request = http.Request('GET', url);
      final response = await client.send(request);
      response.stream.listen((var data){
        print(data);
      });
...


Could this help?

Hey, @Maoaii why don't you consider using Websockets? It will be much less painful to implement streaming over WS! Also I built a chat app using Tornado and Flutter so It might help too

@Chris, i'll take a look at that article, i'll get back to you as soon as I have tried it!

@Khushal, i've tried to use Websockets the first time around, and the behaviour seemed to be the same actually. I'm considering switching back to Websockets though, because if both approaches have the same behaviour, it probably has something to do with another part of my code, not the implementation of the Websockets or Streams

@Khuskal, I managed to get the transmission to work with websockets! I think, since I had a "time.sleep(1)" in my server, and it is a blocking operation, Flutter would wait until end of transmission. Switched it to "await asyncio.sleep(1)", and it's working!
I'm now having trouble decoding a BsonBinary that's being sent, but i'll probably get that working sometime soon.

@Chris, refer to the message above. It's all working!

That's probably happening because you used await on the for loop, which waits for the response.stream to resolve (which occurs when the stream finishes).
Use the await with the data instead. E.g.:
print((await data))

Also add code snippets directly instead of adding screenshots of the code

Thank you for the head up regarding the code screenshots. Already changed them to actual written code.
The response.stream isn't iterable, and i've taken a look at the methods it implements, and I thought that maybe the ".listen" subscription would work similarly to what you mentioned. However, the behaviour hasn't changed. Refer the post's update in the end of it to see what i'm talking about
